# Unix weird directory

Tags: unix

I tried to get a file via ftp from comand line (ssh), I forgot to specify a directory. It shows up as file saved to: â/dev/nullâ

Does that mean that the file was discarded? or is it somewhere saved on my remote machine?

```
Length: 524288000 (500M) [application/zip]
Saving to: â/dev/nullâ
```

Comment: *"... via ftp from comand line (ssh)"*? Do you mean sftp or scp? Perhaps it might help if you show the command you used?

Comment: Are the funny characters at the beginning and end of `/dev/null` (they show up a an 'a' with a caret '^' on top) part of the filename or just mangled markup?

Comment: Rather than just thanking @Jens, it would be more helpful to answer his question, and show us *exactly* what command you used.

Comment: You might want to look for a directory `â` in the current directory with sub-directory `dev` containing a file `nullâ`.  Alternatively, it is just the message that is scrambled, and your file really was saved to `/dev/null`, in which case, it is not going to be possible to get it back (you'll have to FTP it again).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I doubt such a directory would be there. The `â` appears to be a decoding error for quote chars. It [shows up often enough](https://www.google.com/search?q=%C3%A2%2Fdev%2Fnull%C3%A2)  as an output of `wget -O /dev/null`.

Comment: @ShawnChin: I didn't expect the directory to be there but if the message was 'real' rather than noise, that's where it would be.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Apologies, I misread your comment. No condescension intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your file was saved to the null device ([/dev/null](http://linux.about.com/cs/linux101/g/slshdevslshnull.htm)) which is a virtual file that discards anything that is save to it. In other words, the command you used downloaded the file and threw it away.

You'll need to download it again.

#### But why â/dev/nullâ ?

The â's that appeared were meant to be quotes which your terminal may have misinterpreted. See [this page](http://www.downtowndougbrown.com/2012/02/fix-for-putty-displaying-a-instead-of-quotes-when-connected-to-a-linux-machine/) for an explanation, and if the circumstances matches yours, a fix.

Without that encoding problem, you would have seen something like:

```
Length: 524288000 (500M) [application/zip]
Saving to: ‘/dev/null’
```